# Data Driven Pages, displaying each polygon within a ddp?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

I have DDP index, and within each index several sets of polygons from another layer.For each index I would like to display each polygon within that index and export that to a PDF. I can pan to DDP index and set a constant scale in this case 1:24k.  I would like to use the index page for my extent and then for each polygon within that extent export a PDF only showing one polygon. An arcpy.mapping solution seems to be the best option.  as a page definition query seems to be limited to one query per index without much control of what is going to go into the query, other than the page index number.

Below is an illustration:[image]

In this example 019 purple with grey boarders is the index,  I want to maintain the extent of the index and export a map for each blue polygon(10 and 1) which is stored in another layer

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  What happened when you tried to use File | Export Map to do this?  It should be straightforward so if it is not, perhaps re-read that part of the documentation, try again, and if still unsuccessful then use the [edit] button to revise your question.

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague.  However, it sounds like you want to turn on [Page Definition Queries](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/page-layouts/using-page-definition-queries.htm)

Comment: @Fezter I wondered whether that might be what the question was actually about too, but I think page definition queries have one extra level of difficulty for someone new to DDP like this user appears to be.  I'm going to vote for this question to go On Hold for its asker to clarify what is being asked and what has been tried.

Comment: I agree with Fezter. You're trying to use two DDP indexes at the same time, which you can't do. The definition queries will solve it, but since unlike the example you want multiple pages for a given extent, each with a unique polygon (whereas the example shows all polygons within an extent), you would need to duplicate each of your index polygons once for each of the subject polygons that fall within it. If you don't care about having the same extent, you could just use the subject polygons as the index and set a constant 24k scale.

Comment: I think a picture would help clarify what is being asked here.  I find the opening sentence quite confusing "I have DDP index, and within each index several sets of polygons from another layer".  Do you mean "I have the DDP index layer, and within each index polygon I am displaying several sets of polygons from other layers", or something else?

Comment: I thought about just setting the extent to a constant 24k scale and using the smaller polygons as the data driven page, which would work great, but  I do care about the extent being set to the larger polygon.  I also have thought about spatially joining the current index with a one to many type relationship.  But this might not work because it would add a whole another level of tedium if the polygon data changes which it inevitably will.

Comment: took me a second to figure out I could not add the image in my comment

Comment: Think of comments as just being there to give you ideas about improvements you can [edit] into your question which is sometimes all that potential answerers have time to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"layers")[0]
crLyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[2]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[3]
legend = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"LEGEND_ELEMENT","Legend")[0]
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount +1,1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
    rowValue = str(mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.getValue("COMINDEX"))
    query = 'COMINDEX = \'%s\'' % rowValue
    lyr.definitionQuery = query
    rows = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr,["Owner_ID","COMINDEX","SmpleNam"])
    for row in rows:
       v2 = row[0]
       v1 = row[1]
       if(v2<> ''):
           query2 = "%s AND \"Owner_ID\"= %s" % (query,v2)
           print query2
           lyr.definitionQuery = query2
           crLyr.definitionQuery = query2
           legend.title = row[3]
           arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,r"path""" + row[3] +str(v2) + ".pdf")
```